# CSS/HTML Select drop down not highlighting last option

Tags: html, css, select, drop-down-menu

I have a select div with options, and it worked fine before but now the last option is not being highlighted when I hover over it, what could be the issue?

```
<select id='theme_s' title='Click to change your theme'>
    <option value='flame' selected>flame</option>
    <option value='mint'>mint</option>
    <option value='neon'>neon</option>
    <option value='cmd'>cmd</option>
    <option value='sky'>sky</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Yes, I couldn't copy and paste since it's generated in PHP w/ an array, but here is how it looks like after it's loaded: http://puu.sh/6neZW.png (the "sky" option is not being highlighted when I hover it but it does activate once I click on it)

Comment: <select id='theme_s' title='Click to change your theme'><option value='flame' selected>flame</option><option value='mint'>mint</option><option value='neon'>neon</option><option value='cmd'>cmd</option><option value='sky'>sky</option></select>

Comment: is there a link you can share to see this issue in action, the select looks good to me

Comment: Can you provide your CSS classes for your div and maybe your select?

Comment: Tried it on different browsers and it seems to work, guess it's just an issue with chrome on my end, thanks for all the help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Last option in Drop-down is not getting hover effect in Google Chrome 32.0.1700.76 m](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21328796/last-option-in-drop-down-is-not-getting-hover-effect-in-google-chrome-32-0-1700)

Answer (score 2):

This is a known bug of the recently updated version of chrome.
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=334227