# Last option in Drop-down is not getting hover effect in Google Chrome 32.0.1700.76 m

Tags: html, google-chrome, select, webkit, hover

I am testing it on Google Chrome `32.0.1700.76 m`

The last option in the select tag is not getting the hover effect from mouse.

It is highlighting when using through keyboard.

[image]

Comment: I posted it as many people have asked about it to me and they feel there code is having some problem .

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/efLxS/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is Bug . [Issue 336348:Last option of select does not get highlighted on mouse hover](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=336348)

and also see [Issue 334227:[Aura] Regression : Last dropdown item not highlighted on mouse-hover](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=334227)

---

> It's not the problem with your code it's due to Google Chrome Bug.

---

> With more than 3 options this bug comes into play.

---

This issue has been fixed in Google Chrome latest Version `32.0.1700.102 m`.

> Solution Update your Google Chrome to latest Version.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known bug in Chrome `32.0.1700.76 m` on Windows 7, and the [devs are aware of](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=334522), there is a quick fix:

1. Right click the Chrome icon on your Windows Desktop
2. Click Properties
3. Select the Compatibility Tab
4. Check "Disable Visual Themes"

Remember to restart your chrome to make it works.

However, the bug has been fixed in [version 32.0.1700.102](http://googlechromereleases.blogspot.ro/2014/01/stable-channel-update_27.html), released on 2014-01-27.